# Access wordpress blog on subdirectory /blog that is running on subdomain

Tags: php, subdomains, proxy

I have my main site https://1example.com in nextjs and wordpress blog on subdomain https://blog.1example.com. They both are hosted on different servers and diff hostings.

I need my blog to be accessible via subdirectory in main site - https://1example.com/blog

I have successfully proxied nextjs https://1example.com/blog to see blog but blog's internal links, pages, posts, media is still pointing to subdomain.

```
async rewrites() {
return [
  {
    source: '/blog',
    destination: 'https://blog.1example.com/',
  },
  {
    source: '/blog/:slug',
    destination: 'https://blog.1example.com/:slug', // Matched parameters can be used in the destination
  },
]
```

},

I have tried many solutions but end up breaking wordpress config

Need help

solutions tried

- https://medium.com/one-weekend-at-a-time/how-to-reverseproxy-wordpress-at-blog-from-any-sub-domain-ec8e5159e305
- https://proxyscrape.com/blog/using-a-reverse-proxy-to-install-a-wordpress-blog-for-enhanced-seo
- I am also trying to rewrite response from wordpress in case it is called from my main site but so far no luck